# Adding a header to ListView in SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: java, android

So basically I am trying to add a header to a ListView based on a List of letters I have that I will check against with the results from the Cursor.

The current issue is that `parent.addView(View)` is not possible in newView where I need it to happen.

```
@Override
      public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View header = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_patient_header, null);
        String firstName = // substring from cursor;

        TextView testView = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.list_item_header);
        testView.setText(firstName);

        parent.addView(header);


        // Code for view setup to pass to bindView

        view.setTag(holder);
    return view;
  }
```

When I do this on it crashes with error: `addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView`

The basic idea is to create a TextView element that will be a header and that will be outside of the ListElement that is already displaying elements on to the screen.
The result is to make a Header of first letter of people on the list with the corresponding letter.

Comment: So you don't wana a ListView's header ... but listview item that will be a header for some othere items group ... google for alphabetindexer/sectionindexer + headers ... I'm pretty sure that there is some implementation

Comment: @Selvin I am trying to add a separate TextView item in a RelativeLayout based on the current cursor element. So it looks like a header. Thank you for your answer but nothing helps that I found.